# fast forward merging of two branches checkout from same branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have checked out two branches from "master" branch say "feature1" and "feature2".
Lets say "C1" is the head commit of "master" and "feature1" branch has a new commit "C2" and "feature2" branch has a new commit "C3".

How to merge "feature2" in "feature1" branch in fast forward manner if possible else a normal merge?

Please help to avoid the recursive merge as much as possible.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you try to include a branch diagram showing what the state of each branch is?  Otherwise, someone might have to guess at an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your word picture and turn it into an actual picture.  You have the branch name `master`, which points to the last commit in a series of commits.  I'll call this last commit of `master`, which has some big ugly hash ID, `H` here.  Commit `H` records the actual hash ID of its parent commit which I'll call `G`, and so on.  We say that master *points to* `H`, and `H` *points to* `G`, and so on.

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

These *points to*s are actually part of the commits, except for the very last pointer that comes directly from the name `master`.  Commits, once made, can never be changed, so `H` forever points back to `G`.  Branch names, however, can be changed at any time!  Since the ones inside commits are wired down forever, and I want to draw ones that point back (leftward) but also upward or downward, let's connect these with lines, and reserve the moveable arrows for the branch names.  (If I had different kinds of arrows I could draw in text, I'd use strong, diamond-like, unchangeable arrows for the internal commit arrows, and big soft easily-bent ones for the branch names.  But I have to work with text-art here.)

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

You added a new branch name `feature1` and another new branch name `feature2`, so that all three names point to commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, feature1, feature2
```

Then, while on `feature1` you made a new commit you are calling `C1`:

```
$ git checkout feature1
... do work, git add files ...
$ git commit
```

which resulted in this:

```
             C1   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, feature2
```

Note that `feature1` has `HEAD` attached to it.  That's how Git knew, when it created new commit `C1` pointing back to existing commit `H`, that the *name* to move was `feature1`.  The name `HEAD` is still attached to `feature1` right now, with the name `feature1` pointing to `C1`, and `master` and `feature2` still pointing to `H`.

Now you run:

```
$ git checkout feature2
```

which—along with preparing your work area for working with commit `H` again—attaches `HEAD` to the name `feature2`:

```
             C1   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, feature2 (HEAD)
```

Commit `H` is the one you now have extracted into Git's *index* and your work-tree, so now you do some work again, `git add` to update the index, and `git commit` to make snapshot `C2` from the updated index.  This moves the name `feature2` to point to commit `C2`:

```
             C1   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             C2   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Now you say this:

> How to merge "feature2" in "feature1" branch in fast forward manner if possible else a normal merge?

A *fast forward* operation consist of taking one of these branch names, such as `master`, and "sliding it forward" (rightward, in our picture, opposite the way the internal arrows go) so that it points to some other commit.  From the *new* commit, we *must* be able to work our way back to the original commit.  If we can't do that, the move we made is not a fast-forward.

Thus, we can fast-forward `master`, which currently points to `H`, so that it points to `C1` or to `C2`.  That slides it forward and up, or forward and down, and either way we can start from where we land, and work our way backwards to `H`.  But how will you slide the arrow *forward* from `C1` so that it points to `C2`?  You can't: it's quite literally impossible.  You can slide it *down*, so that it points to `C2` and forgets `C1` entirely, but that is not what you want.

Therefore, we have to fall back on a normal merge.  To do that:

```
$ git checkout feature1
$ git merge feature2
```

This will do a real merge, not a fast-forward.

> Please help to avoid the recursive merge as much as possible.

A real merge *is* a recursive merge,<sup>1</sup> so it's not possible to combine commits `C1` and `C2` without doing a merge.

For more on how merge works, see any number of other StackOverflow postings or a good book on Git.

Note that you have one other option: you can *copy* commit `C2` to a *new and different* commit `C3`.  We could call it `C2'` instead of `C3` to indicate that it's a copy of `C2`.  Suppose we changed *two* things about this new copy:

- The starting source tree will be that of `C1`.  We'll apply to this source tree, any changes we made in terms of `H`-vs-`C2`.
- The parent of the new copy will be `C1`, not `H`.

If we draw this new commit in, it looks like this:

```
               C2'  <-- ???
              /
             C1   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             C2   <-- feature2
```

Once we make this `C2'` copy of `C2`—and have some branch name that *finds* commit `C2'`—we'll have a commit that we *can* use for a fast-forward.  The name `feature1` can now slide forward-and-up, so that `feature1` points to `C2'`:  From `C2'` we can go back to `C1` and then back to `H` and `G` and `F` and so on.

The easy way to make `C2'` is to use `git cherry-pick`, which copies commits.<sup>2</sup>  The easy way to do this with branch `feature2` is to use `git rebase`, which uses `git cherry-pick` to copy commits, then *moves the branch name* to point to the *copied* commits, abandoning the originals in favor of the new copies.  But that's a topic for another question (and rebasing is already well-covered in other StackOverflow postings).

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, *recursive merge* is a particular *merge strategy* in Git.  There are some other built-in strategies—`resolve`, `octopus`, and `ours`—but none of them are going to be helpful in this situation.

<sup>2</sup>This copying via cherry-pick uses Git's merge engine, so you're *still merging!*  You cannot get away from merging.  Embrace merging!  Learn it and love it because you will be using it frequently.